# MYSQL stored procedure, case

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, case

I've consulted this page: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/case.html as well as this one, but can't get a simple procedure to work....

---

UPDATE: 
To clearify what I want to do: I want to select all rows from a table where the field id is either 1, 0 or could be either of them. This is specified by an input parameter to the procedure, which takes values 0,1 or 2.

So if _id = 0 I want:
select * from TABLE where id = 0

If _id = 1 I want:
select * from TABLE where id = 1

And if _id = 2 I want:
select * from TABLE where id in (0,1)

I was hoping I could get the rest of it to work by myself if I only got the simple case-statement below to work...

---

What I want to do is something like:

```
begin
    select * from TABLE where
        case _id
        when  0 then id=0
        else id = 1
        end as id
end
```

which gives error "You have an error in your SQL syntax".

I've also tried:

```
begin
    select * from TABLE where
        case _id
        when  0 then id=0
        else id=1
        end case
end
```

which gives the same error. Obviously I've got the wrong syntax somewhere, but I can't figure out where... Can anyone help me out?

Thanks,
Niklas

Comment: What are you trying to do? `WHERE` is used for choosing rows, why do you have a variable assignment in it?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, your first attempt was close. Try instead `select * from table where id = case _id when 0 then 0 else 1 end`.

Comment: So, I tried

begin
 select * from table where id= case _if when 0 then 0 else 1
end

Produces: "MySQL Error Number 1064 - You have an error in your SQL-syntax........."

Comment: Where does `_id` come from? Also, if you run the query without the `BEGIN ... END` does it work?

Comment: _id is an integer which comes as a parameter to the procedure. If I run the query in the command window, after assigning a value to the _id variable, it works. However, not in the stored procedure

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not good with MySQL procedures - nearly zero experience with them - but I'd expect that if the SQL works in the command window it *should* work in a procedure. It may be an error elsewhere in your procedure. If you can't figure it out, I'd recommend posting the entire procedure (with the working query) as a new question. Sorry I can't help any further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
begin
    select *,
        case _id
        when 0 then 0
        else 1
        end as id
    from table
end
```

When used as part of a `SELECT` query, `WHEN` is not a statement, it's a [control flow function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case).

You can also express this as:

```
begin
    select *, _id != 0 as id
    from table
end
```

Answer (score 0):

build the query to look like this... mySQL case have a different syntax from C and Java...

```
set @input=2;

select * from foo 
 where 
     case when @input =2 then  value in ( 1, 0)  else
       value =  @input end;
```

[live demo with sql fidle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/34a1e/30)

Comment: Thank you! I will try that tomorrow when I have access to the database and let you know if it solved my problem or not.