# Cannot create stored procedure MySQL

Tags: mysql, syntax

I am trying to create a stored procedure, but I am having an issue.

```
    delimiter |
create procedure get_user_credits_2(guid char(50))
BEGIN
SELECT user_credits.GUID,
    creditwarninglevel,
    creditsexpirydate,
    EmailCreditWarningLevel,
    EmailAddressWarningLevel,
    CustomerName,
    CASE WHEN user_credits.Credits > 0 
         THEN sum(user_credits.Credits) + SUM(user_credits.PurchasedCredits)
         ELSE   user_credits.Credits
    END AS 'Credits'
FROM
user_credits
WHERE guid=iguid;
END
|
delimiter ;


Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax, check the manual to your mysql server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 15.
```

I have checked a few sources, but I can't get this to work. I'm sure it is probably something I am over looking. Thanks

I have checked another question as well on here source: [MYSQL stored procedure, case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17658984/mysql-stored-procedure-case)

Image:
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue, for some reason in Navitcat IDE doesn't like the fact you declare a procedure and start with

```
BEGIN

END
```

It only cares about the select statement. eg

```
Select * from table;
```